# test of ICMP block

Tags: internet-connection, http, curl, connection, icmp

In my bash scripts I have been using something like:

```
until fping -u google.com; do echo "$0[$$] Network/DNS down?? $(date)" 1>&2 && sleep $(($RANDOM%(1 + ++trynum * 1) +1)).222; done
```

to test for online connectivity.

It halts in place, sleeping growing random intervals, until it can ping google.com again.

Problem:
On some LANs ICMP pings are blocked altogether, although web pages are still reachable.  What's a short way to test for this general case (firewall to outside)?

Based on that test I will switch over to an http-based test like the exit status of

```
curl -s google.com >/dev/null
```

if that is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Using curl is rather wasteful of bandwidth. Just use [tcping](http://www.linuxco.de/tcping/tcping.html) instead.

Other options if you don't have that:

```
curl -sI -m 2  http://www.google.com >/dev/null
echo 'HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n' | nc www.google.com 80 >/dev/null
```

The basic idea is to make a TCP connection to port 80 and see if that succeeds.

Comment: Good tool, but doesn't seem universal.  I would have to deploy on each Ubuntu/cygwin server I have control over.  Looking for a more portable way.

Comment: @marcos What do you have? zsh? netcat?

Comment: on most Ubuntu hosts: bash, dash, ash, socat, netcat/nc, nmap, fping, arping, mtr, traceroute, netstat, netpipes(faucet hose), curl, wget, no zsh ...

Answer (score 1):

If some server is blocking ICMP requests, you can still check if the web server is reachable by a short port scan e.g. with [nmap](http://nmap.org/):

`nmap -PN -T4 -p 80 your_webserver 2>&1 | grep -wi open >/dev/null || date`

Comment: Okay, except `nmap -PN -T4 -p 80 sgasdfoogle.com || date` doesn't execute date as desired; apparently the exit code is still 0 when hostname can't resolve (or reachable?)

Comment: @Marcos: Add `grep "open"`.

Comment: true.  `nmap -PN -T4 -p 80 sgasdfoogle.com |grep -wi open || failcode`